# macro vba Replace all symbols after or before definite one

Tags: vba

Pleas help me to find out where is my mistake.

I have a string 80/120 in cell A1 and I want to create a variable, replace all symbols before "/" (including "/") and put it in cell B1.

> ```
> Sub secondmacro()
> Dim ReplaceSmth As Variant
>
> ReplaceSmth = Cells(1, 1)
> ReplaceSmth = Replace(ReplaceSmth, "*/", "")
> Cells(1, 2) = ReplaceSmth
>
> End Sub
> ```

Can't figure out why it doesn't change anything and I get 80/120 value in B1

LPChip gave me greate idea how to do that!

I modify your code a little to fulfill my needs:

> ```
> Sub secondmacro()
>
>  Dim ReplaceSmth As Variant, CellPosition As Integer
>
>   ReplaceSmth = Cells(1, 1)
>   CellPosition = InStr(1, ReplaceSmth, "/")
>
>
> If CellPosition <> 0 Then Cells(1, 2) = Mid(ReplaceSmth, CellPosition + 1, Len(ReplaceSmth))
>
> End Sub
> ```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace does not understand wildchards. It only replaces literal texts. [See here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php) for more help about the function Replace.

What you want to do instead is first find the position of the first /, then get the text and set it to the first cell, then repeat the process but for the remaining text, and set it in the second cell.

Your macro will look something like this:

```
Sub secondmacro()
    Dim ReplaceSmth As text, CellPosition as Integer

    ReplaceSmth = Cells(1, 1)
    CellPosition = InStr (1, ReplaceSmth, "/")

    If CellPosition > 1 then
        Cells(1, 1) = MID(ReplaceSmth, 1, CellPosition)
        Cells(1, 2) = MID(ReplaceSmth, CellPosition, len(ReplaceSmth)-CellPosition)
    end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the value of `CellPosition` before you start calling `Mid`. Right now if there is no `/` in the cell then your code will crash.

Comment: @Richard Good call. Edited.